# Trying to copy range-selected data from one DB to another; can I speed up this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `state_changes` (
    `node_id`   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
    `id`        INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Disambiguates states from the same second",
    `health`    ENUM('0','1','2') NOT NULL,
    `dataUID`   VARCHAR(255) NULL COMMENT "Link to further information (not always given)",

    PRIMARY KEY (`node_id`, `timestamp`, `id`),

    -- This is used by certain queries
    UNIQUE KEY `IdentityId` (`node_id`, `id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

 CREATE TABLE `further_information` (
   `dataUID`    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   `station_id` VARCHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
   `snr`        DOUBLE,
   `toa`        DOUBLE,

   PRIMARY KEY (`dataUID`, `station_id`)

   -- Oh for InnoDB!
   -- FOREIGN KEY `dataUID` (`dataUID`) REFERENCES `state_changes` ON DELETE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Data:

```
 INSERT INTO `state_changes` VALUES
   ('a', '2015-11-24 00:00:00', 1, '2', NULL),
   ('b', '2015-11-24 00:00:00', 2, '2', NULL),
   ('c', '2015-11-24 00:00:00', 3, '2', NULL),
   ('a', '2015-11-24 06:31:24', 4, '0', 'a1'),
   ('a', '2015-11-24 06:31:40', 5, '2', NULL),
   ('b', '2015-11-25 17:09:11', 6, '0', 'b1'),
   ('b', '2015-11-25 18:46:59', 7, '2', NULL),
   ('c', '2015-11-26 23:22:00', 8, '0', 'c1'),
   ('c', '2015-11-26 23:23:05', 9, '2', NULL)
 ;

 INSERT INTO `further_information` VALUES
   ('a1', 'x', 1.23, 4.56),
   ('a1', 'y', 2.34, 5.67),
   ('a1', 'z', 3.45, 6.78),
   ('b1', 'x', 3.21, 6.54),
   ('b1', 'y', 4.32, 7.65),
   ('b1', 'z', 5.43, 8.76),
   ('c1', 'x', 9.87, 9.87),
   ('c1', 'y', 8.76, 8.76),
   ('c1', 'z', 7.65, 7.65)
 ;
```

Queries:

```
-- This is really fast; uses primary key when table is large
SELECT * FROM `state_changes`
  WHERE `node_id` IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
    AND `timestamp` >= '2015-11-25 00:00:00';

-- id  select_type  table          type   possible_keys  key      key_len  ref  rows   Extra
-- 1   SIMPLE       state_changes  range  \N             PRIMARY  261      \N   14827  Using where


-- This... is not :( I'm surprised the PRIMARY key doesn't jump in here.
SELECT * FROM `further_information` WHERE `dataUID` IN (
  SELECT `dataUID` FROM `state_changes`
  WHERE `node_id` IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
    AND `timestamp` >= '2015-11-25 00:00:00'
);

-- id  select_type         table                type            possible_keys  key      key_len  ref    rows       Extra
-- 1   PRIMARY             further_information  ALL             \N             \N       \N       \N     403640706  Using where
-- 2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  state_changes        index_subquery  \n             PRIMARY  258      func   1          Using where
```

#### ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32247/1))

My intention is to throw these queries into an `INSERT INTO tbl SELECT * FROM ...`, to copy all data since the 25<sup>th</sup> November from one such database into another.

The real tables have 35 million and 403 million rows, respectively.

How can I make the `further_information` query behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-write `IN` as a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM `further_information` f
  JOIN `state_changes` s ON f.`dataUID` = s.`dataUID`
WHERE s.`node_id` IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
 AND s.`timestamp` >= '2015-11-25 00:00:00'
```

Perhaps you need to do `SELECT DISTINCT`? (Depends on the data.)

```
SELECT f.*
FROM `further_information` f
  JOIN (select distinct `dataUID` from `state_changes`
        WHERE `node_id` IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
         AND `timestamp` >= '2015-11-25 00:00:00') s ON f.`dataUID` = s.`dataUID`
```

Comment: Wow that appears to be it. Why is there such a big difference? What I wrote seemed expressive! I did also try with a JOIN rather than a subquery, but by joining the tables the other way around lol

Comment: The simple answer: `IN ( SELECT ... )` is poorly optimized.  See also http://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/